# 'ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending' in using postgres 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am working on an RoR application.
I am getting the following error
[image: error message]

The specs are as follows :

```
Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)
Postgres 10.14
Ruby 2.4.4
Rails 5.1.6
```

I have tried

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

I have also tried to resolve the error with

```
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

Yet it's the same error.
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What output shown when you run ```bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development```?

Comment: -bash: bin/rails: Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your question is `Permission denied` when you run `bin/rails`,just

```sh
chmod u+x bin/rails
```

make it executable.